# Closure of Set in Zariski Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $U$ is a set in affine space, is the closure of $U$ simply $V(I(U))$? If so, how might one prove this?

Comment: Yes. This follows from chasing through the definition of the Zariski topology.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. This is a basic fact about the Zariski topology. You can find the proof at page 3 of Hartshorne - Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 1.2(e). And here is a hint if you want to show it yourself: show that for any closed set $Y$ that contains $U$, it must be the case that $Y$ must contain $V(I(U))$.